# Best practice to handle the FB access token in custom API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, restful-url

I have developing a restful api where the client provides a facebook user id (let say `myapi/get_user/123`) and the API must retrieve user's public information like name, birthday, etc. That it's done.

**Current code**:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => $fbSettings['app_id'],
        'app_secret' => $fbSettings['app_secret'],
        'default_graph_version' => $fbSettings['default_graph_version']
]);

$token = 'EAAD...';

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $fbResponse = $fb->get('/' . $request->getAttribute('id') . '?fields=link, name, birthday', $token);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    return $response->withStatus(500)->withJson(['msg' => $e->getMessage()]);
  exit;
}

$user = $fbResponse->getGraphUser();
return $response->withJson($user);
```

My problem it's that I don't know what is the best way to handle the access token. Should the token be provided by the client? In that case, should pass as param in the same request (e.g: `myapi/get_user/123?token=ABC123`) or should do another api call (let say `myapi/register_token/ABC123`) breaking the principle of being stateless.

I looking for the best way (or the best practice) to handle the access token.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to pass access token is in authorization request header :

```
 GET myapi/get_user/123 HTTP/1.1
 Host: mysite.com
 Authorization: <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Comment: Is there a way in that the client  doesn't need provides the facebook access token in order to simplifying the use of my api?